# Getting a "your password no longer matches your keyring" error when I try to access my VPN on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I had to reset my root password and now I'm having this issue when I try to access my VPN on Kali Linux:

```
Your password no longer matches your keyring.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

All the solutions I can find are for Ubuntu and don't seem to to work for Kali.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem before finding this thread, here. I think, or better said, I'm sure that removing `~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring` will work on older versions. I have recently upgraded to kali 2020.1 and this is what worked for me. You can remove the login.keyring file altogether. If you consider you may need it, just make a backup:

```
cd ~/.local/share/keyrings/
cp login.keyring login.keyring.backup
```

Check it with `ls`
I had both files, login.keyring and login.keyring.backup, along some other.
I have removed without remorse the login.keyring one.

```
rm  -f ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```

After checking with `ls` you'll see that it was removed. I did that operation which triggered the annoying popup, and this time the popup didn't show up. Good luck!

Comment: This worked for modern versions of Fedora.

Comment: nazar2sfive worked for fedora rawhide 36

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring` file. After that, you should be prompted to set a new password. Make sure it matches the one used for logging in.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago.
It didn't accept my new root password.
It worked when I typed in the default Kali root password "toor".

Maybe that works for you too.